# Do you have to show a WIZZ boarding pass on a computer screen for it to be printed for free at the airport?

Tags: tickets, check-in, wizz-air

With easyJet, you can get a boarding pass at the airport for free if already checked in online, no hassle.

However, when I asked a WIZZ check-in counter in London, they said they can only print it for free if I show the PDF boarding pass on my notebook screen.

Is this actual WIZZ policy? I assume check-in staff can see electronically that I am checked in, so what would be the purpose of me having to show the PDF boarding pass?

Comment: Maybe they want to see that you generated the boarding pass, not simply just checking in.  Then they would accept the fact that you were unable to print it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Article 9.7 of [Wizz Air's General Conditions of Carriage](https://wizzair.com/static/docs/default-source/downloadable-documents/20160226-gcc_en_v2-sfvrsn-f2d1d106_129_4c1872603c677770ee487d05505995a4.pdf) states:

> [...] You must print the Boarding Pass no later than 2 hours prior to the departure time according to the Schedule and present it together with Your valid Travel Documents used during online check-in at airport security and at the boarding gate. If You fail to print Your Boarding Pass 2 hours before the time of departure according to the Schedule, You must pay the airport check-in fee at the airport. [...]

I didn't see anything else that looked relevant, either on the company website or in their conditions of carriage. So it seems that what happened to you was, indeed, against Wizz Air's policy, but in a way that benefited you.

I'm not a Wizz Air employee so I don't know the reasons behind their policy.

Comment: From my past interactions with W6, I'd be very surprised if they were willing to print a boarding pass for free at any airport except ones which explicitly don't permit printed-at-home/mobile boarding passes (eg KUT)

Comment: @davidvc At KUT you're expected to hand in the printout at the check-in desk and have it exchanged for a "regular" BP

Comment: Seems like Wizz Air uses every kind of little tricks to get 35 Euro out of you, they play against their clients.

I checked in on their site from my mobile and they displayed the message "You have successfully checked in 2 persons of 2.".

Answer (score 5):

Seems like wizz air uses every kind of little tricks to get **35 Euro** out of you for check in. They purposely make check-in process very hard to follow.

I checked in on their site from my mobile and they displayed the message "You have successfully checked in 2 persons of 2". When I arrived at the airport I noticed that email they sent after check-in didn't contained boarding pass and when I went back to my booking on the the wizz air page, I saw the message "**You must download your boarding pass 2 hours prior to the flight**". So I had to pay 70 Euro. There is no explanation for this scam behavior.